# Multiple subscriptions made with shareReplay?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following method:

```
isLoggedIn() : Observable<boolean>{
  return this.isLoginSubject.asObservable().shareReplay(1).do(x=>console.log('called'));
}
```

In several components, I have the following code:

```
isLoggedIn: Observable<boolean>;
this.isLoggedIn = this._authService.isLoggedIn();

<header id="toolbar" *ngIf="isLoggedIn | async as isLoggedIn">
    <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
</header>
```

I noticed when I login, `'called'` is printed 4 times to the console.  I thought `shareReplay` would only cause one subscription?

Service:

```
export class AuthService {
  isLoginSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.tokenNotExpired());
  private sharedLogin$ = this.isLoginSubject
  .shareReplay(1)
  .do(x => console.log('called'));

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  authenticate(username, password) {

   const user = {username, password};
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   return this._httpClient.post<any>(environment.api_url + '/auth', user, {headers: headers}).do(x=>{

     this.isLoginSubject.next(true);
   });

  }
```

Component (ts):

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn = this._authService.isLoggedIn();
   }
```

Component (HTML):

```
<div [class]="bodyClasses">
  <aside id="sidebar" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : mobileNav }" (click)="mobileNav = !mobileNav" *ngIf="isLoggedIn | async as isLoggedIn">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  </aside>

  <main id="main" class="wrapper">
    <header id="toolbar" *ngIf="isLoggedIn | async as isLoggedIn">
      <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
    </header>
    <div id="content">

      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

I remove the `...| async` and noticed only one `called` in the console, but when I log out, it doesn't trigger a change. The components that should be hidden on logout are still showing:  I am doing the following in logout:

```
 logout() {

    this.isLoginSubject.next(false);


  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling the `this._authService.isLoggedIn()` method multiple times which creates the chain `this.isLoginSubject.asObservable().shareReplay(1)...` multiple times (for each call of this method it creates a new chain) so if you see `'called'` printed 4 times it's because you're subscribing to 4 different chains.

So instead you can put the chain into an object property and just return it from the `isLoggedIn()` method:

```
private sharedLogin$ = this.isLoginSubject
  .shareReplay(1)
  .do(x => console.log('called'));

isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.sharedLogin;
}
```

Or you can just make the `sharedLogin$` public and subscribe directly to it.

Comment: That's correct because you have `do` after `.shareReplay(1)`. In other words there're 4 subscriptions to `do` and to `.shareReplay(1)` but `.shareReplay(1)` keeps only one subscription to its parent. Add another `do` before `.shareReplay(1)` and see how many times this is invoked.

Comment: Thanks martin. That was it.